# Piping with ">>" into /etc/locale.gen - permission denied with sudo

Tags: bash, shell-script, pipe, manjaro, locale

I'm trying to run the command:

```
$ sudo echo ko_KR.UTF-8 UTF-8 >> /etc/locale.gen
```

but I get `permission denied`. Strangely, it doesn't  even ask for my password with sudo.

However, if I type

```
$ su
# echo ko_KR.UTF-8 UTF-8 >> /etc/locale.gen
```

It works.

I've tried this on two Manjaro installations - same problem. While the `su` method works, I'm trying to write a guide so I want to keep it simple.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? It seems like I'm doing some unintended bash syntax.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out -

The shell does the piping, not the process. `sudo echo` doesn't give bash the privileges to edit `/etc`. Here's a workaround I found:

```
echo ko_KR.UTF-8 UTF-8 | sudo tee -a /etc/locale.gen
```

Now I'm feeding the output of `echo` into something with sudo privileges (tee) which simply writes to the file.

If anyone finds a simpler way of doing this I'll mark that as the correct answer instead :)

Comment: This is the usual and easiest way to do it, I think you can mark your own answer as correct :)